# Objective-C Threading

Tags: objective-c, multithreading

I wanted to learn more about threading in objective-c, so I made a little test program that would just loop and output what iteration of the loop it is on. 
However, the output I am getting is not what I am expecting. I have an idea as to why, but first here is my code:

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "Car.h"


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        Car* myCar = [[Car new] autorelease];

        [myCar performSelectorInBackground:@selector(LoopAndSay) withObject:nil];

        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
        {

            NSLog(@"Main loop on %i", i);
        }


    }
return 0;
}
```

Car.m

```
#import "Car.h"

@implementation Car
@synthesize name, model;

-(void) LoopAndSay {

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Looping for the %i time", i);

    }

}
@end
```

Now, if I run it as is the background loop will sometimes not complete(stopping between iterations 94 and 97). Additionally, if I switch my code around so that the background loop is not called until after the main thread loop then it will not run any iterations. 
Is this because the main thread is finished and does not want to wait for the background thread to run to completion? If this is the case, is there a way to force the program to continue running until both the main thread and any background threads are complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly because <strike>you exit the scope of the autorelease pool before the thread completes</strike> your `main` function returns before the background thread completes. Try adding `sleep(3)` or something before its end and see if your background thread completes.

On Mac OS X, a process terminates when all its "foreground" threads have completed. `peformSelectorInBackground:` only creates a background thread, so once `main` returns, you're left with no foreground thread and your process is terminated.

Comment: I would also like to add that everything starts execution from the main.m If it is not called from main.m, or something that is called from main.m doesn't call your function it will not be executed.

Comment: I had not even considered that I was exiting the scope of the autorelease pool before the background thread completes(or even starts). It makes a lot more sense now. Thanks!

Comment: @DanielMartin, do read the edits, though. It's not because you exit the scope of the autorelease pool, it's because you leave the `main` function.

Comment: @zneak I just ran a small test to check and see if it would run after the autoreleasepool was drained, and now reading your edit I get what is happening. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

This is because all threads created with `performSelectorInBackground:...` and other Objective-C APIs are *detached*, so that the program can terminate without waiting for them to finish. From the [Threading Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW3):

> At application exit time, detached threads can be terminated immediately but joinable threads cannot. [...] If you do want to create joinable threads, the only way to do so is using POSIX threads...

In this case, your main thread loop happens to finish a bit sooner than the background thread, so the background thread loop doesn't run through to the end. Instead of using POSIX threads (which is much less convenient), you could also use `NSOperationQueue`, which easily allows you to wait for all operations in a queue to finish.